# Keeping multiple net-snmp sessions open at the same time

Tags: c++, multithreading, snmp, net-snmp

I have a list of snmp clients(mostly Linux PCs) which I need to poll every minute for their network statistics(IF-MIBs). For the purpose I use net-snmp in c++. In every minute, for every client, I open a net-snmp session, poll the client and close the session. Is there any way I can keep the sessions open for each client throughout the program execution time? As far as I know, Net-snmp does not allow two sessions (for two clients) to be open at the same time. I need to close the session of one client to open the session for the next client. This becomes hard when the client count increases.

Comment: I removed the "c" tag since you mentioned you use c++. c and c++ are different languages and usualy should not be both tagged.

Comment: "Net-snmp does not allow two sessions..." does not sound right to me. What makes you think that? Anyway, your question would probably get more traction if you structured it along the lines of: I tried making two sessions at the same time `code` ([mre]) and it failed with `error message`.